# "use strict" for legacy browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to add `"use strict";` statement in to my function. but it is not supported to legacy browser's like ie7,ie8. is there any way to achieve this functionality to legacy browsers.

can any one explain use of `use strict` with program. i know little bit .but i am not really understanding well about use of strict. but in my company they suggested follow ecma5 standards
Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't figure out what solution there can be but you can't just add the directive and ignore its side effects on legacy browsers because it isn't backwards compatible. The line itself will not trigger a syntax error but it'll change the code behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can just include the `"use strict";` directive in your function, and if the browser does not support it, the directive will just be ignored. You would not want to rely on strict mode to make your function work.

Comment: If you want to make sure your code is compliant with ECMAScript5 standards, include it and test it in a modern browser. The directive does not affect the functionality of your script, it will just prevent it from being run. So as long as it works on a modern browser, you know it will also be strict compliant on older browsers

Comment: Just as `;` is allowed as an empty statement (inherited feature from C) `"some string";` is also allowed. This ensures old browsers will just see an empty statement - and ignore it. New JavaScript engines will look for an empty statement of the form `"use strict";` and apply the ES5 strict mode from there, within that scope (function).

Comment: @egucciar: That is true for most cases, but there is actually some cases where strict mode *changes* how the script works.

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: @Guffa good tip. Didn't know that. I'll have to read more about how strict mode affects the way the code runs!